# Error while upgrading AWS Glue from 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

While upgrading an existing job from AWS Glue 2.0 to 3.0, the current scala version is 2.11.8 and Spark is 3.1

```
Exception in User Class: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
```

**Error stacktrace:**

```
ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): Exception in User Class: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
com.utils.CommonUtils.getPathPrefixFromFilePath(CommonUtils.scala:41)
com.awsutils.S3Service.downloadObject(S3Service.scala:169)
com.ValidateHealthData.getDatesToValidate(ValidateHealthData.scala:67)
com.ValidateHealthData.validateHealthData(ValidateHealthData.scala:46)
com.ValidateHealthData.main(ValidateHealthData.scala:287)
EtlMain$.main(EtlMain.scala:106)
EtlMain.main(EtlMain.scala)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:48)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.invoke$(ProcessLauncher.scala:48)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:90)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:161)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:30)
com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)
```

Could you please advise what I could do to fix this upgrade issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the docs with the title [Migrating AWS Glue for Spark jobs to AWS Glue version 3.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/migrating-version-30.html) says:

> - Do your jobs depend on Scala 2.11?
>
>   - AWS Glue 3.0 uses Scala 2.12 so you need to rebuild your libraries with Scala 2.12 if your libraries depend on Scala 2.11.

Based on you said that the scala version you are using is `2.11`, you should first upgrade to `2.12`. At least, that should be one of your issues.

---

The migration guide explains how you should proceed to migrate `AWS Glue 3.0`. You have a section named `Actions to migrate to AWS Glue 3.0` and also another one named `Migration check list`.